# How to disable iPod Music Control when device screen is locked?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'm using MPMusicPlayerController in my app and it works fine in background.

The problem is I don't want user to control the song via iPod music app while device is locked?

Thank you for any helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have knowledge in ipod.

As on IOS, You should detect when device goes sleep/lock mode. When the device goes lock/sleep, then u can control your music in sleep mode method function.